# How can I get Resharper to insert highlighted text on Intellisense listbox to editor when press enter?

Tags: resharper

As I am typing certain functions or variables, Resharper suggests a possible list (Intellisense) of names below my cursor. It will highlight the text on the suggested list box that it thinks is the closest to what I am typing. This is good.

However, when the highlighted  element on the list is correct, and I press enter, it goes to the next line. I thought it would be more intuitive if it inserts the highlighted text on the suggested list into where my type cursor is at on the editor. To get the text from the Intellisense listbox into the editor, I have to press the Up/Down arrows on my keyboard to focus on the Intellisense listbox and then press enter. This is quite cumbersome. In Eclipse, the text gets inserted into the editor when I press enter.

How can I set Resharper or Visual Studio 2012 (which ever's fault this problem belongs to) to insert the highlighted text on its Intellisense list to the editor instead of going down to the next line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know exactly if I get it right, but it seems that you get so called "soft" completion, where ReSharper is trying not to mess with your typing. If so, then you can use `Tab` to finish completion instead of `Enter`. Or you can go to `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | Autopopup`, find your case and change value from `Display and do not preselect` to `Display and preselect`.

If that is not your case, then please specify ReSharper version and code sample, we'll look into it.

Comment: You can also use ctrl-enter to complete "soft" completion (shown as an outline rather than a full line select). And it's worth knowing that for normal completion, enter will insert and tab will replace.