# ReSharper intellisense autoselect first option

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

Basically, I want ReSharper's intellisense to work a lot like IntelliJ's, where all I have to do is press enter. I hate having to press down when selecting a option that's the first on the list and pressing enter, its slower than actually typing it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Resharper to insert highlighted text on Intellisense listbox to editor when press enter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276630/how-can-i-get-resharper-to-insert-highlighted-text-on-intellisense-listbox-to-ed)

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276630/how-can-i-get-resharper-to-insert-highlighted-text-on-intellisense-listbox-to-ed?newreg=0592757281ad4c77ae9b5642120c04a5)
This is really what I needed but in a different question, more of like a switcherooni :\ really wish this was pointed out better..

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*